# How to install npm in alpine linux

Tags: linux, alpine-linux

So I can't get to install npm in alpine linux. I thought perhaps I can just do a `apk add npm` but apparently `apk search npm` returns nothing, even after a `apk update`. I'm experimenting with all this from the nginx:alpine docker image, i.e. `docker run -it nginx:alpine /bin/sh`

Edit 1: I can see how the [nodejs:alpine](https://github.com/mhart/alpine-node/blob/master/Dockerfile) dockerfile builds `node`, but I don't understand how it builds `npm`

Edit 2: now that I know that npm gets installed with nodejs on alpine, and just for clarification, the reason this wasn't evident to me at first is that on ubuntu 14.04 a `sudo apt-get install nodejs` would still require a `sudo apt-get install npm` (which installs development packages e.g. `gcc`)

Answer (score 197, accepted):

For the recent versions of Alpine (v3.8+) the correct way to install nodejs with 
npm is:

`apk add --update nodejs npm`

However, `npm` package depends on `nodejs`, so you can do:

`apk add --update npm`

Note: since Alpine 3.8 there is no nodejs-npm package.

Comment: How do we install a specific version of nodejs?

Comment: @JollyRoger specify the version to the apk command `apk add --update nodejs=12.20.1-r0`

Comment: @eemelipa Just wanted to note that this is not a good idea when containerizing your application.

Comment: @S.SaeidHosseini could you elaborate a bit more why specifying exact version is not good idea with containers?

Comment: @eemelipa since not all versions of node.js will be available through alpine repositories forever, you'll need to continuously update your Dockerfile with the latest available version, to docker/CI build errors.

Comment: In 2022, `apk add --update nodejs npm` works for me.

Answer (score 205):

I had an issue with the apk manager.

The package **nodejs** is no longer installing NPM (see [pkgs.alpinelinux.org](http://pkgs.alpinelinux.org))
You have to install nodejs-npm

```
apk add --update nodejs nodejs-npm
```

Comment: I do not understand it. Npm should be the core dependency of node, npm install npm@latest might be impacted by the node version itself so they would not be compatible...

Comment: This should be the accepted answer with the latest alpine image.  npm was not installed for me with just nodejs

Comment: Agreed, this is _normally_ a dependency, but if you're installing nodejs manually (I was installing it from the 'edge' repo as well because as of now 6.7 is deprecated) then you need to install nodejs-npm separately

Here's what I ran:
apk add nodejs=6.11.2-r0 nodejs-npm=6.11.2-r0 --update-cache --repository http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/main/ --allow-untrusted

Comment: Side question: while this answer works just fine, I can't seem to find `nodejs-npm` on https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/packages. There is `npm` package which also does the job. Is it some kind of alias?

Comment: the correct answer is the correct answer

Comment: nodejs-npm is no longer available, now it's just "npm"

https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/package/v3.14/main/x86_64/npm

Answer (score 31):

I could be wrong, but I think `npm` is actually a dependency of `nodejs`.

I've never seen any flavor of package manager install `npm` alone. Always seems to come packaged with `yum install nodejs`, or `apt-get install nodejs`, or `apk add --update nodejs`.

Comment: this is no longer accepted, as apk does not installs npm by default when installing nodejs

Comment: upvoted just because nobody provided a better answer

Comment: I believe it is 'apk add --update nodejs-npm' for Alpine 3.6+

Comment: `npm` isn't a dependency of `nodejs`. Some using `node` might prefer to use `yarn` instead as package manager.

Answer (score 9):

`apk update && apk add nodejs` installed the `npm` binary for me.

Comment: Disputing if something works should include versions of things...

Answer (score 5):

The issue here is a recent one and is due to changes in Alpine's package repositories between v3.5 and v3.6 or edge.

In v3.5 `nodejs` included npm
In v3.6 `nodesjs` does not include npm and the new `nodejs-npm` package exists.

See [here](https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/packages?name=nodejs&branch=&repo=&arch=&maintainer=) for Alpine packages.
To see what version of packages you are pulling from look at the contents of `/etc/apk/repositories`

Answer (score 3):

npm comes hand in hand with nodejs.
In the case you cant install node with apk add nodejs, you need fix that first.
Step 1 - do you have the [community repo](http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/latest-stable/community/) added to your /etc/apk/repositories list? If not, it is very useful to do so. Further details: https://wiki.alpinelinux.org/wiki/Enable_Community_Repository

Comment: Can you explain the down vote?

Answer (score 3):

I could successfully install nodejs and npm in alpine Linux with the below commands. Added benefit for this method is we can choose different node version with nvm

```
apk add -U curl bash ca-certificates openssl ncurses coreutils python2 make gcc g++ libgcc linux-headers grep util-linux binutils findutils

curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.39.1/install.sh | bash

export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"

[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"

nvm install -s <version>
```

For reference visit [here](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm#installing-nvm-on-alpine-linux)

Answer (score 2):

I have just had to this and can confirm that npm is not a dependency of node.js (at least right now on alpine) and must be installed seperately

i.e `apk add --update npm`

Answer (score 1):

I needed latest/current node (v20 at time of writing), but right now I only see node v18 on https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/packages?name=nodejs&branch=edge&repo=&arch=&maintainer=
[image: screenshot of the link]

However, digging around nodejs.org download options, I found this:

```
apk add --update nodejs-current npm
```

[image: screenshot of nodejs.org]

NOTE: `nodejs-current` doesn't seem to include npm, so I needed to add  `npm` to end of the command.