# What is the best way to install latest nodejs with npm on alpine linux

Tags: packages, node.js, alpine-linux

I am trying to build my own docker container based on alpine linux and I need to add multiple services in that container (yes it is not recommended as best practice but at the moment my org devops is bit behind the curve and demanding a single dockerfile for my custom image).

I was checking [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1125969/how-to-install-npm-in-alpine-linux/1164122#1164122?newreg=4ee5a97da4aa4415ab3055c4aeb3b64c) article to find the way to install the latest version of nodejs with npm on alpine linux. However there seems to be no `apk add nodejs@6` or something like that provided in this discussion.

Also it appears that alpine linux does not have the latest version of nodejs (v 8.X) in the repository [here](https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/packages).

So do I pretty much have to install nodejs from source? 
But that option is very slower compared to just installing from alpine repo.

**EDIT:**

adding nodejs-current in dockerfile is giving another problem

> Step ... : RUN apk update && apk add nodejs-current
>
> ---> Running in e430b4d279e5 fetch http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.4/main/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
>   fetch
>   http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.4/community/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
>   fetch
>   http://nl.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/testing/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
>   v3.4.6-213-gb6db4bd [http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.4/main]
>   v3.4.6-160-g14ad2a3
>   [http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.4/community]
>   v3.6.0-3765-g46dd4472f4
>   [http://nl.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/testing] OK: 8679 distinct
>   packages available ERROR: unsatisfiable constraints:   nodejs-current
>   (missing):
>       required by: world[nodejs-current]

Comment: You know, there's [unix.se] for that.

Comment: Well ... the nature of this question is such that it could be posted here also.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

We provide two nodejs packages:

- [nodejs](https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/package/v3.6/main/x86_64/nodejs) in main – LTS version,
- [nodejs-current](https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/package/v3.6/community/x86_64/nodejs-current) in community – the current version, as its called by upstream.

So if you want the latest version, install nodejs-current by running:

```
apk add nodejs-current
```

Currently it’s 7.10.1 in v3.6 (stable branch) or 8.5.0 in edge (unstable/rolling branch).

We don’t use `@N` suffixes like `nodejs@6`, it’s not a valid package name.

Comment: I’ve explicitly stated that you should install nodejs-current from Alpine branch v3.6 or edge, but you’re using v3.4 repositories… v3.4 is quite old. And mixing v3.4 with current testing is extremely bad idea btw…

Comment: Oh OK! In that case, I will have to wait until the standard PHP image I am using (php:7.1.9-fpm-alpine) update their alpine repo to V3.6 (they use V3.4).

Comment: No, in that case you should stop using such horribly outdated image! Just use base alpine image and install php7-fpm package.

Comment: BTW The answer is right, it’s not my fault that you haven’t read it properly, so it’s quite rude to downvote it.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way for me was to use a specific version of Alpine.

In my use case I've used `php:7.4-fpm-alpine` image. And have to update it to `php:7.4-fpm-alpine3.13` to be able to use Node 14.

```
php:7.4-fpm-alpine3.13 - Node 14
php:7.4-fpm-alpine3.12 - Node 12
```

Dockerfile example:

```
FROM php:7.4-fpm-alpine3.13

RUN apk update && apk add nodejs npm
```